# Dynamically querying database using WHERE clause

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I want to query a table dynamically to set up my code to work autonomously. in this instance the best method to use is the `WHERE` clause. so that is what I've done. I've created a function in my database but for it to work on different data in the database. I need to pass a parameter which would query that specific data that I need queried. Now the problem that I have is that I don't want my user to pass this parameter but rather I want to pass this parameter through my code but so far I just can't figure out a way to do it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION comm_profile(p_artist VARCHAR(60)) 
    RETURNS BIGINT
AS 
$$

DECLARE

total       BIGINT;

BEGIN
    
    WITH temp AS (
        SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_spotify WHERE artist = p_artist
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_tidal WHERE artist = p_artist)
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_soundcloud WHERE artist = p_artist)
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_youtube WHERE artist = p_artist)
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_youtube_music WHERE artist = p_artist)
        )
        SELECT SUM(plays) FROM temp INTO total;
        RETURN total;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Example

```
SELECT artist, plays FROM machine_spotify WHERE artist = p_artist

comm_profile('Drake')


machine_spotify table
| artist | plays |
|:-----  |:----- |
| Drake  | 161371|
| Drake  | 273973|

Output
| comm_profile |
|:------------ |
|  435344      |
```

```
auth_user table

| id | username    |      artist     |
|:---|:--------    |:--------------- |
|  1 | J.cole12    |      J.cole     |
|  2 | Drake01     |      Drake      |
|  3 | cassper59   | casspernyovest  |
|  4 | Kendricklmr | Kendrick Lamar  |

SELECT artist FROM auth_user

Output
|      artist    |
|:-------------- |
|      J.cole    |
|      Drake     |
| casspernyovest |
| Kendrick Lamar |
```

I don't want this I want it to return a singular artist but I cant think of a query that would allow that without requiring a parameter

now what I want to do is to create another function that will give me the `Drake` but I can't quite pin down the method. selecting the column `artist` brings back the whole column as oppose to how I want them. Which is 1 by 1. creating a while loop does the same. how do I solve this?

Comment: 1) What has this to do with `psycopg2`? 2) Provide example data showing what is happening now and what you want to happen.

Comment: I've added the code that includes psycopg2. I'm using psycopg2 in order to pass into my python code.

Comment: Yes, but `psycopg2` has nothing to do with the question you are asking it is just the client you are using to run the function. You still need to provide the data examples.

Comment: I edited it and added an example to further illustrate

Comment: Do you a table that stores just the `artist` information?

Comment: I do but when I query it. it returns the whole column but I want it 1 by 1. something like a loop returning 1 item at a time.

Comment: Add that query and output to your question. Also explain "want it 1 by 1".

Comment: Still not sure what "1 by 1" is? Would this not work?: `SELECT artist, comm_profile(artist) FROM auth_user;`,

Comment: And ... where is your python code??

Comment: Well if you want to only return a single artist you will have to specify that in the query: `SELECT artist, comm_profile(artist) FROM auth_user where artist = <some_artist>`.